# Take the sum of two integers and add another integer to the sum continuously

Tags: c++

I would like to make a C++ program that takes the sum of two integers and adds another integer to the sum continuously. Please help, I'm a beginner. My code looks like this, except it doesn't update the next sum:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int x;
  while (cin>>x){
      int y=100;
      int sum;
      sum = x+y;
      
      cout<<sum<<endl;
 
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you dont want to lose the previous result, you should update the previous result. So you can change with sum=sum+x+y; or simply sum+=x+y;
And also @scrappedcola is right, you should declare the sum variable out of the loop.

Comment: Redefining sum on every iteration of the loop isn't helping any either.

Comment: define ALL your variables above the loop.  Making a new sum variable for every input doesn't work.  Also, your title says "add another integer to the sum" but you aren't doing that - you should be `sum = sum + x;` but make sure that sum has an initial value when you define it above the loop.

Comment: Your loop body is equivalent to `cout << x + 100 << endl;`. Can you spot the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `sum` variable is declared inside the loop body, so it will be wiped out on each iteration.  You need to move that variable outside of the loop, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int sum = 100, x;
  while (cin >> x){
      sum += x;
      cout << sum << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This code plus the comments earlier about me declaring the sum inside the loop made me realize my mistake.